# Fluentd, Elasticsearch and Kibana Setup

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd

I am trying to setup Fluentd, Elasticsearch and Kibana in my local environment (Ubuntu 14.04LTS). I am new to this kind of technology and i just followed this article:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/elasticsearch-fluentd-and-kibana-open-source-log-search-and-visualization

This one i don't have: Droplet with Ubuntu 14.04

But aside from that I did not experience any error and i think i installed everything properly. But when i access my domain, kibana is only showing this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFqxl.png

"Upgrade Required Your version of Elasticsearch is too old. Kibana requires Elasticsearch 0.90.9 or above."

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: can you run the following command and post the results? curl -GET 'localhost:9200'

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you haven't downloaded the most recent Elasticsearch version?

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to incompatible versions of Elastic search with your kibana version.

Execute the following command on your ubuntu shell.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'
```

The output would have a similar section,

**"version" : {
    "number" : "1.4.0.Beta1",**

The number in the output gives the current ES version. If the version is not greater than 0.90.9 download the latest stable ES and set it up.

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed everything following this blog:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/elasticsearch-fluentd-and-kibana-open-source-log-search-and-visualization

But after installing everything following the link above, elasticsearch's version was still not the most recent so i followed this blog:
http://blog.bekijkhet.com/2014/06/install-elasticsearch-in-ubuntu-1404.html

After that it's working.